# Managing Dynamic and Informal Contracts, Agreements, or Rules

Tags: document-management

I'm looking for something to manage and maintain agreed-upon rules between or among parties with ongoing changes and revisions to these rules.

This is not meant to be anything formal requiring legal review, but simply documenting and capturing understanding between individuals such as roommates or parent/child.

Ideally the current agreed-upon rules would be available for viewing from a smart phone, and the in-progress draft would be available for editing from a smart phone as well.

It would be great if the software will track change proposals and revisions as well at the item level, and baselines/releases of the final set.

Consider two roommates writing down a roommate agreement today capturing a single rule that they both agree to abide by:

```
Roommates agree not to leave dirty dishes in the sink.
```

Tomorrow they decide to revise and/or extend the entire set of rules:

```
Roommates agree to promptly place dirty dishes in the dishwasher.

Roommates agree to place milk back in the fridge.
```

For each rule, it is tracked that Roommate 1 proposed the new or initial wording, and that both roommates approved (and, thus, agreed to) the final wording, and the final wording of all the approved rules has been baselined into a single set of rules.

Answer (score 0):

Most word document type of software have this type of functionality built in.

A document can be set up to have dynamic revisions and changes with colour coding assigned to each of the participants.

Words can be edited, deleted, added with a clear history of the changes made.

The the document can be regularly updated and changes can be accepted or rejected by the document manager.

Give [google docs](https://thesweetsetup.com/apps/the-best-online-collaborative-document-editing-suite/) and/or [office 2016](https://www.howtogeek.com/230319/how-to-collaborate-on-documents-in-real-time-in-office-2016/) try to see if they meet your requirements.